# Multiple database queries in a WCF web service?

Tags: c#, sql, database, web-services, wcf

I've been asked to build a web service (IIS hosted) which will be consumed by an ESB process, and the web service needs to run 3 queries against 3 separate databases to gather the data required.

Once gathered, some advanced transformations will occur within the WS (hence why we aren't transforming directly within the ESB process which has limited transformation capabilities).

My question is.. is it seen as an acceptable approach to run 3 DB queries within a web service? If not what other approaches would be recommended?

I do appreciate the more DBs I query, potentially reliability could decrease but we have load balanced and clustered DB farms so generally the web service should always be able to connect to the DB servers

Thoughts on approaches?

Comment: Three questions. First of all, how many people will be executing this web service and second, how often will they be executing this web service and third, does the data need to be realtime data?

Comment: Hi, 1) Just an ESB process (no people), 2) Service will probably be called every few minutes throughout a day, 3) Yes data has to be real time, we can't cache anything unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't implement caching of any sort, it seems your requirements dictate you query the three different sources.

As for the best approach, I would consider [Parallel Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel(v=vs.110).aspx), of which you can even set a timeout using `CancellationToken` on the tasks to ensure you don't exceed the WCF response timeout.

Comment: Yes parallel tasks is something I'm also looking at :) Although if I'm honest my initial thought was to just use the Connection Timeout param in the conn string of each connection and setting it low (ie 5 opposed to default 15) to try keep response times down just 'in case' a DB was unreachable.

Comment: Why does everyone immediately go for Parallel Tasks and similar "innovations" these days :). What's wrong with starting 3 threads for each query and then just waiting for them to finish with `Join()` (which also accepts a timeout if you want to put one)? :)

Comment: @Developr You may want to set the DB connection timeout as well, but unless you use separate threads you'll have to wait on the total of all calls.

Comment: Yeah @xpa1492, I realize that's essentially the same thing, but TPL is sooo nice! :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your tasks.  You can use three queries for three databases if you don't need to guarantee [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).

If you need to use transactions you can use [transactions in WCF services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff384250.aspx).  But be aware that transactions are meant to be short-lived and flowed transactions can increase transaction time.